# How to ignore or disable nextpage tag?

Tags: pagination, the-content, wp-link-pages

I have this site that uses the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in posts for pagination purposes. I want to disable pagination, but without deleting the tags for the database (maybe they'll want to use them again in the future).

Tried removing `wp_link_pages();` from the template, but then it would only show the first page's content without the links - I don't know if that's how it should work or something wrong.

How can I make it that wordpress simply ignores `<!--nextpage-->` and display the full post at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `the_post` filter, to override the content pagination, that takes place within the `setup_postdata()` function ( *PHP 5.4+* ):

```
/**
 * Ignore the <!--nextpage--> for content pagination.
 * 
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183587/26350
 */

add_action( 'the_post', function( $post )
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) 
    {
        // Reset the global $pages:
        $GLOBALS['pages']     = [ $post->post_content ];

        // Reset the global $numpages:
        $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

       // Reset the global $multipage:
        $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
    }

}, 99 );
```

to ignore the `<!--nextpage-->` feature.

The global `$pages` variable contains the paginated content:

```
$pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);
```

so that's why we need to restore it to:

```
$pages = array( $post->post_content );
```

We actually don't need to restore the `$numpages` variable, but we do it as part of the house cleaning. If we only restored `$pages` and `$numpages=0` then we would get:

```
<div class="page-links">Pages:</div>
```

The `wp_link_pages()` function [checks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L779) if the global `$multipage` is true to display the content pagination output. So that's the variable to set to false to remove the whole output. We could also use the `wp_link_pages` filter to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeing it would be simpler than adding hooks, but it did work like charm

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Other approach would be to just remove it from the database (or just rename it) with a SQL query. But since you want to have the ability to turn it on again and handle new posts containing it, then I think the filtering solution is more suitable in this case. @LucianDavidescu

Comment: [Here's another way](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/26350) to do this via the new `content_pagination` filter. @LucianDavidescu

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `<?php $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false; ?>` in your loop.
if doesn't show paginator in mobile:

```
wp_is_mobile()
$GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
```

I hope it is helpful for you