# How to disable content pagination?

Tags: posts, pagination, the-content

I want to totally disable this functionality from WordPress because I'm implementing my own version of this with Javascript.

When I try to grab all the content in a post via the `get_the_content()` or `the_content()` it gives me only the first page, since the content has the page breaks. When I use `$post->the_content` I get the full post but it's not formatted with HTML tags. I don't want to have to add those myself programatically.

So I either need to get all the content already formatted - the way to do this is unknown to me at the moment
or disable `wp_page_links()` so it doesn't paginate my posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT -** Now that 4.4 is out, you should use the `content_pagination` filter. See birgire's answer below.

---

You can add formatting to raw post content by [applying](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) the [content filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) directly to `$post->post_content`:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

This will bypass pagination by not using the `get_the_content` function, which is what `the_content` uses internally to retrieve the current page's content for multipage posts.

You can prevent `wp_link_pages` from outputting anything by applying a filter to its output before the function is called and using the [`__return_empty_string`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string) helper function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Comment: Das it mane. That did the trick. You da man(or wo-man).

Answer (score 8):

### New content pagination filter in WordPress 4.4

As of WordPress 4.4 we can use the `content_pagination` filter ( see ticket [#9911](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9911) )

```
/**
 * Filter the "pages" derived from splitting the post content.
 *
 * "Pages" are determined by splitting the post content based on the presence
 * of `<!-- nextpage -->` tags.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array   $pages Array of "pages" derived from the post content.
 *                       of `<!-- nextpage -->` tags..
 * @param WP_Post $post  Current post object.
 */
 $pages = apply_filters( 'content_pagination', $pages, $post );
```

This filter lives in the `setup_postdata()` method of the `WP_Query` class and will make it easier to modify the pagination pages.

Here are few examples how to remove the content pagination (PHP 5.4+):

### Example #1

Here's how we can disable the content pagination:

```
/**
 * Disable content pagination
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/26350
 */
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];
    return $pages;
} );
```

### Example #2

If we want to only target the *main query loop*:

```
/**
 * Disable content pagination in the main loop
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/26350
 */
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    if ( in_the_loop() )
        $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];

    return $pages;
} );
```

### Example #3

If we only want to target `post` post type in the main loop:

```
/**
 * Disable content pagination for post post type in the main loop
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/26350
 */
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages, $post )
{
    if ( in_the_loop() && 'post' === $post->post_type )
        $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];

    return $pages;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Glad to know there is now a filter to make our lives easier :-)

Comment: absolutely, looks like the 4.4 release is scheduled early December  @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 2):

You can kill the "link pages" functionality in one filter by stripping the `nextpage` markers out of the post content:

```
function kill_pages($posts,$qry) {
 if ($qry->is_single()) {
  $posts[0]->post_content = preg_replace( '/<!--nextpage(.*?)?-->/', '',  $posts[0]->post_content );
 }
 return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts','kill_pages',1,2);
```