# How to ignore pagebreaks for RSS feed?

Tags: pagination, rss

I use default page break tags in my posts and unfortunately RSS feeds do not show the full content without the page breaks. I am currently using WordPress 4.5.3.

I have "For each article in a feed, show" settings set to "Full text".

What can be the problem and if this is not a problem, what's the best way to fix this in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean how to ignore `<!--nextpage-->` in the feed content, then we can adjust [this approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208784/26350) for feeds:

```
/**
 * Disable content pagination for feeds
 */
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    if ( is_feed() )
        $pages = [ join( '', (array) $pages ) ];

    return $pages;
} );
```

where `$pages` is an array that contains the content parts.