# Set URL Parameter Post Layout As Default

Tags: functions, urls, parameter

I have 2 urls:

- www.site.com/post1/
- www.site.com/post1/?content=onepage

I have the following function that controls the layout of the post through the URL parameters in **BOLD**:

www.site.com/post1/**?content=onepage** activates the function below:

```
    function onepage(){

        // condition(s) if you need to decide not to disabling shortcode(s)
        if( empty( $_GET["content"] ) || "onepage" !== $_GET["content"] )

            return;

        // Condition(s) at top are not met, we can remove the shortcode(s)


    function remove_shotcode($content) {
        return str_replace('[/shortcode1]', '', $content);    
        return str_replace('[shortcode2]', '', $content);
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shotcode', 6); 

    /**
     * Ignore the <!--nextpage--> for content pagination.
     * 
     * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183587/26350
     */

    add_action( 'the_post', function( $post )
    {
        if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) 
        {
            // Reset the global $pages:
            $GLOBALS['pages']     = [ $post->post_content ];

            // Reset the global $numpages:
            $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

           // Reset the global $multipage:
            $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
        }

    }, 99 );
    }

    add_action('wp','onepage');
```

How to make the url **www.site.com/post1/** and **www.site.com/post1/?content=onepage** load the same function by default.

I think it just need a simple condition for:

This one is for parameter **content** set to **onepage**

`if( empty( $_GET["content"] ) || "onepage" !== $_GET["content"] )`

And another for **if no url parameters set**.

Comment: Can you indent your code? It looks like you have nested functions, never nest function definitions like that

Comment: Thanks! I indented the code. Don't know enough to either agree or disagree on the nested functions

Comment: Are you doing this just for a specific post (e.g. post with the slug `post1` as in your example), or just any posts?

Comment: I want this to apply to all posts

Comment: Not sure if the answer helps, but that's an example for single posts, but also supports URLs having the `content=onepage` query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this to apply to all posts

First off, making the `content` query string defaults to `onepage` is actually equivalent to enabling the `onepage()` for all URLs/pages.

And for example to enable it by default on single post pages only (for *any* post types), then you can replace this:

```php
if( empty( $_GET["content"] ) || "onepage" !== $_GET["content"] )
    return;
```

with this:

```php
if( ! is_single() && ( empty( $_GET["content"] ) || "onepage" !== $_GET["content"] ) )
    return;
```

which means the `onepage()` would also be applied on pages/URLs where the `content=onepage` presents in the query string.

Check [the developer docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) for other conditional tags like `is_singular()`.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Awesome! " ! is_single() && " part did the trick. Thanks!